# Flyway in a Netbeans module: unable to resolve location

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, flyway

I have a Maven Netbeans module with flyway dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In the location src/main/resources/db/migration I have the sql file named V1__Base_Version.sql.

I'm calling from the module like this:

```
// Create the Flyway instance
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    // Point it to the database
    flyway.setDataSource(getStorageDatabaseURL(),
            getStorageDatabaseUsername(),
            getStorageDatabasePassword());
    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
    flyway.setCleanDisabled(true);
    //option: flyway.setLocations("classpath:db/migration");
    // Start the migration
    flyway.migrate();
```

Based on [flyway documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java.html), that should be the default path, but it didn't work, meaning that the migration files were not found.

Any options/ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? What error and/or debug output are you getting?

Comment: Added clarification. I meant that the migration files were not found.

Comment: You should completely verify that the migrations location is exactly

'src/main/resources/db/migration'

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone was still looking for a solution, I was able to successfuly use Flyway inside a Netbeans module by applying the following trick:

- Assuming that your migration folder is `db/migration/`, add an empty class in the *parent* folder (i.e. `db/`) and mark this *parent* package (i.e. `db`) in NetBeans module as public package. After this a NetBeans ProxyClassLoader is able to successfuly answer for `getResources("db/migration")` query issued by Flyway (tested on NetBeans 11.1).